# Is there any point of calling poll() after produce if we are not using delivery callback in kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are trying to optimize our python app that produces message to kafka topic via confluent python kafka client and using confluent control center we can check whether particular message is delivered to kafka topic or not, so now question is should we be using poll() function after produce since delivery callback is now removed and will it led to better throughput if say we are producing 100K messages in 1 Sec.

```
producer.produce( topic=topicName, value=msg, key=msg_key)
producer.poll(0) # Is poll now required
```

We are using confluent python api that internally uses librdkafka and as per that if produce request is successfully handled by broker then the success response is enqueued in delivery report queue and will be passed to application on poll call so if there is no poll does that mean delivery queue will be completely filled up after some time and can create issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still need to call poll() so that the internal delivery report callback is triggered.

But you really do want to use a delivery report callback, otherwise you have no indication whether messages could be produced or not. At least add a log message for failed deliveries.